# Add increments to a CSS class

Tags: php, css, increment

I need to be able to add an increment to a class name. I've looked for solutions for this, and they don't work for my example.

I have a foreach loop in which I want to add a sequential number 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. to the class 'section_0'.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
<div class="menu-section-container">


<?php

// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('section_container') ):

// loop through the rows of data
while ( have_rows('section_container') ) : the_row();

    if( have_rows('sub_section_container') ):

    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('sub_section_container') ) : the_row();

        if( have_rows('food_item') ):

        // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('food_item') ) : the_row();

$menu_contents = array( the_sub_field('section_heading'), the_sub_field('item_name'), the_sub_field('price'), the_sub_field('item_description') );

$counter = 1;

foreach ($menu_contents as $menu_content); { ?>

<div id="section_0<?php echo $counter++; ?>" class="tabcontent">
<?php echo $menu_content; ?>
</div>

<?php $counter++; // increment before foreach ends
}

        endwhile;
        else :
        endif;

    endwhile;
    else :
    endif;

endwhile;
else :
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();

?>

</div> <!-- section -->
```

Comment: What is the output your getting?

Comment: @NigelRen Red It's returning the class name and number 1 for each group. So basically "section_01" for all of them, not "section_01" ,  "section_02",  "section_03" etc.

Comment: You should make sure your indenting reflects your code structure. It’ll save you quite a few headaches.

Comment: You can also tidy the code up by removing some of the unneeded `else : endif;` segments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to set your `$counter` further up. So -

```
$counter = 1;
```

Would probably be better somewhere like after

```
if( have_rows('section_container') ):
```

You can try it in different places to see how it works best for your setup.

Also - in this section of the code, your incrementing `$counter` twice (using `$counter++`).

```
<div id="section_0<?php echo $counter++; ?>" class="tabcontent">
<?php echo $menu_content; ?>
</div>

<?php $counter++; // increment before foreach ends
```

You can remove one of them and you should get the numbering your after.

Comment: The first ++ was me trying something out, sorry should have removed it before post.  Moving the $counter up worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `$counter` variable has to be echoed without the `++`:

```
<div id="section_0<?php echo $counter; ?>" class="tabcontent">
```